# IViewLocalizer returns the wrong language

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to build an ASP.NET Core application that should be available in English and German. My problem is `IViewLocalizer` always returns the German text, even with culture set to English. How do I get the right text for the current culture?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       
    services.AddLocalization(opt => opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var cultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("de") };
    app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions 
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
        SupportedCultures = cultures,
        SupportedUICultures = cultures                
    });

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
          routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
               template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization;
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>@Localizer["Hello, World!"]</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>CurrentCulture: @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture</li>
            <li>CurrentUICulture: @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Resource File is located at `Resources\Views.Home.Index.de.resx`

Expected output:

```
Hello, World!

CurrentCulture: en
CurrentUICulture: en
```

Page output:

```
Hallo Welt!

CurrentCulture: en
CurrentUICulture: en
```

Request Headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:61904
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
```

Comment: Can you share how the request looks like including the headers?

Comment: I opened an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/277 but we need a repro. Can you supply that?

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/277 no repro, it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I have made some repro code available on Github: https://github.com/christianheld/ResourceManagerIssue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is having this issue with ASP.NET core 1.1 or newer, try adding `<NeutralLanguage>YOUR_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE</NeutralLanguage>` to your `.csproj` like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
<ApplicationIcon />
<Win32Resource />
<NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It solved my issue and it's now working correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem since yesterday.
It looks like that the LocalizationProvider fails to set the correct culture.
After implementing a custom LocalizationProvider, the `IViewLocalizer` started to work perfectly for `Views` and `ViewComponents` as well.

Also I had to implement the language into the url in the following way:

`http://somedomain.com/<2-letter-iso-language-name>/controller/action`

Here is what I did:

**Startup.cs**

```
public static string defaultCulture = "uk-UA";

public static List<CultureInfo> supportedCultures
{
    get
    {
        return new List<CultureInfo> {
            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
            new CultureInfo("uk-UA"),
            new CultureInfo("de-DE") };
    }
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method I added the `CultureToUrlActionFilter()`. It retrieves the 2-letter language code from url and sets the correct `CultureInfo`. If the Url contains a not allowed culture code, it redirects to the default culture.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
        .AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(new CultureToUrlActionFilter()); })
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

In the Configure method I set up the custom localization provider and inserted it as first in the provider queue:

```
var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions() { 
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultCulture),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures, 
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures };
options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new UrlCultureProvider());
app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
```

If the url contains no culture code after the domain name, I do a Redirect to `http://somedomain/<2-letter-culture-code>` (to the default culture). Urls always must have culture specified.

Routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
     routes.MapRoute("home_empty", "", defaults: new { culture="", controller = "Home", action = "Redirect" });
     routes.MapRoute("home", "{culture}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

I do the redirect it in HomeController, Redirect action

**HomeController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Redirect() { 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { culture = Startup.defaultCulture }); 
}
```

**UrlCultureProvider.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Globalization;

namespace astika.Models
{
public class UrlCultureProvider: IRequestCultureProvider {

    public Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
        var pathSegments = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Trim('/').Split('/');

        string url_culture = pathSegments[0].ToLower();

        CultureInfo ci = Startup.supportedCultures.Find(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() == url_culture);
        if (ci == null) ci = new CultureInfo(Startup.defaultCulture);

        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = ci; 

        var result = new ProviderCultureResult(ci.Name, ci.Name);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
}
```

**CultureToUrlActionFilter.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace astika.Models
{
public class CultureToUrlActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        bool redirect = false;
        string culture = context.RouteData.Values["culture"].ToString().ToLower();

        redirect = String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture);

        if (!redirect)
        {
            try
            {
                CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);
                redirect = Startup.supportedCultures.FindIndex(x => x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.ToLower() == culture) < 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                redirect = true;
            }
        }


        if (redirect)
        {
            CultureInfo cid = new CultureInfo(Startup.defaultCulture);
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { culture = cid.TwoLetterISOLanguageName, controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
        }
    }
}
}
```

The resx files are all located in the same folder

    `/Resources/Views.Home.Index.en.resx
    /Resources/Views.Home.Index.de.resx
    /Resources/Views.Shared.Components.Navigation.Default.en.resx`

etc

Comment: I opened an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/277 but we need a repro. Can you provide that?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/277 no repro, it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: What framework are you targeting? On desktop, Asp.Net Core requires targeting .NET 4.6 or higher to flow cultures correctly across async calls. This does not apply if you're targeting .NETCoreApp1.0